# Does @Transactional open a Session and binds it?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-aop

If I annotate a method that is executed in a thread with @Transactional, will a Session be created and bound to the thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The proxy (`TransactionInterceptor`) is around the service, so for each invocation of a service method it will start a thread-local transaction.

I would advise you to use spring 3 `@Async` so that you leave the thread creation to the container (spring).